# How do I find a specific installed app on the device?

Tags: c#, wpf, mobile, windows-phone-8

I need to know if one specific app is already installed. I'm developing a Windows Phone 8.0 application. I tried to do this by searching on the registry but got `Registry` class not found:

```
key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall");
        foreach (String keyName in key.GetSubKeyNames())
        {
            RegistryKey subkey = key.OpenSubKey(keyName);
            displayName = subkey.GetValue("DisplayName") as string;
            if (p_name.Equals(displayName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == true)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot check to see what apps are installed on a user's phone, for security/privacy reasons.

You can launch apps also developed/published by you though. Check out this page for details: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/jj207014(v=vs.105).aspx